# How to init integer in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I define

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int currentUserNum;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isAlive;
```

in `@interface MyClass`

and defined `-init` method in `@implementation MyClass`

```
@synthesize currentUserNum, isAlive;
-(id) init {
  if (self = [super init])  {
     self.currentUserNum = 0;
     self.isAlive = YES;
  }
  return self;
}
```

`self.currentUserNum = 0;` is crashed , but `self.isAlive = YES;` can work ! They are both `assign` property.

I want to know why ?  Thanks!

Comment: In the init, why have you not returned self after calling [super init]?

Comment: sorry , I had super method

Comment: What is the error when the app crashes?

Comment: @EliGregory The retain count of an `int`?  I don't think so....

Comment: Yes， xcode can not retain int .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `init` method is missing a lot of important code.

```
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _currentUserNum = 0; // it's not wise to reference properties in the init method
    }

    return self;
}
```

Every `init` method should follow this basic pattern. You assign `self` the value of calling an appropriate `super init` or other `self init`. If that's not `nil`, you then perform appropriate initialization code, and finally you return `self`.

Comment: sorry , I had super method and update my question. One more question: Does `_currentUserNum = 0` == `currentUserNum = 0` ? You know, I have defined `@synthesize currentUserNum;`

Comment: Depending on the compiler and your @synthesize, the ivar will either be named `currentUserNum` or `_currentUserNum`. One will compile, one won't.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I need to update my question , please check it again !